# Can you be metaphorically abrasive to something?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, metaphors

I just made the statement:

> I’m abrasive to poetry.

And I was told that it’s not grammatically correct. Does it make sense?

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect, it just doesn't mean what you likely intend it to mean.  If your intent is to say that you find poetry abrasive then your statement is not correct.  However if you mean it as: you abrade poetry then it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Jim what's the difference between the two? What is like to say is that I find poetry abrasive.

Comment: Sandpaper is abrasive to wood.  Wood is not abrasive to sandpaper.

Comment: You can certainly be abrasive to *poets,* as the first-person narrator of Richard Russo's *[Straight Man](https://books.google.com/books?id=LK1VJHw8gOgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=straight+man&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qpYhVY-bLcaSsAWb24CACA&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=straight%20man&f=false)* found out (to his cost in blood) in Chapter 1.

Comment: You can find poetry abrasive, you can find poets abrasive, you may even find me abrasive (as hard as that is to believe).  But you'd have to try pretty hard to abrade poetry.

Comment: @HotLicks Actually, wind and sand of done quite a bit of that over the millennia, whether we are talking inscriptions or papyri.

Comment: I think the construction you're reaching for is the sarcastic (and hackneyed) "I'm *allergic* to X".

Answer (score 1):

If you find poetry *abrasive* where you mean it is *annoying*, you should express it that way: "I find poetry abrasive."

You can't switch the words around and have it still make sense. Take, for example, the sentence "I find math confusing." You can't say "I'm confusing to math" because that switches the entire meaning. Instead, you'd have to say "I'm confused by math."

If you want to express it in that sentence structure, you could say "I'm abraded by poetry." However, the connection between "abrasive" and "abraded" is not intuitive and your meaning might be unclear.